# How to read "List Separator" settings from Regional configuration of control panel?

Tags: c#, configuration, region, controlpanel

I'm making multi culture plugin for MS Word,Excel
where I need to identify setting value provided in Regional Settings under "List Separator" Option, how can I read using C# ?

This List separator is later on being used to construct Excel formulas, word mail merge header, etc.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` or `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").TextInfo.ListSeparator` if you look for a specific culture's information.

Comment: Just as a side note if you plan to use CurrentCulture: make sure there is no code that change the Thread Culture.  

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CA");`  


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx

Comment: If someone changes the current culture of the thread it's usually to make the new settings effect things like these (exports, format). That's why there are two current cultures: one for the thread and one for the UI (CurrentUICulture). Just make sure you are using the one you need, and don't worry if someone changes it.

Comment: To clarify @AlexMazzariol comment, which seems to imply that threads only have one culture: Threads have both CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture. CurrentCulture determines formatting rules for dates, numbers, etc., while CurrentUICulture determines the language used.